# Return async function in realtime firebase database

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I'm still starting to program and I'm a little confused with my async function.

I'm trying to fetch the last data from the last day in my firebase realtime database, I get it as you can see in my console.log inside the function

however when I try to return this value from within the function and it comes with all the data for that last day.

in my realtime firebase database is this way:

[image]

my function is:

```
public async findLatestWeatherStationRecord(): Promise<WeatherStation> {
  const RefR = database.ref('Prototipo0/Leitura/');

  const latestWeatherStationRecord = await RefR.limitToLast(1).once(
    'value',
    snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(child => {
        database
          .ref(`Prototipo0/Leitura/${child.key}`)
          .limitToLast(1)
          .once('value', snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
              const lastMeasurements = childSnapshot.val();
              console.log(lastMeasurements);
              return lastMeasurements;
            });
          });
      });
    },
  );
  // console.log(latestWeatherStationRecord.val());
  return latestWeatherStationRecord;
}
```

the result of console.log inside the function looks like this:

```
{
  anemometro: 2.8,
  bh1750Luminosidade: 1185,
  bmp280Altitude: 653.58,
  bmp280Pressao: 94739,
  csmsv12Solo: 40.76,
  dht22Temperatura: 27.9,
  dht22Umidade: 31.7,
  mhrdMolhamento: -0.04,
  pluviometro: 0,
  timestamp: 1598554509834,
  uvm30aIndiceUv: 1
}
```

I'm breaking my head now, because the return of this function does not give the same result as the return inside the function (console.log). It returns all data for that day and not the last of the function

```
    ...,
    '-MFlG2p4zMPCC7iQ6Y1D': {
      anemometro: 3.73,
      bh1750Luminosidade: 1187,
      bmp280Altitude: 653.27,
      bmp280Pressao: 94742,
      csmsv12Solo: 40.81,
      dht22Temperatura: 28,
      dht22Umidade: 32.5,
      mhrdMolhamento: -0.04,
      pluviometro: 0,
      timestamp: 1598554389829,
      uvm30aIndiceUv: 1
    },
    '-MFlGHWOxi16Qc2HEPba': {
      anemometro: 2.8,
      bh1750Luminosidade: 1184,
      bmp280Altitude: 653.72,
      bmp280Pressao: 94737,
      csmsv12Solo: 40.79,
      dht22Temperatura: 27.9,
      dht22Umidade: 31.6,
      mhrdMolhamento: -0.04,
      pluviometro: 0,
      timestamp: 1598554450009,
      uvm30aIndiceUv: 1
    },
    '-MFlGW78ZQcHJ8reA0YD': {
      anemometro: 2.8,
      bh1750Luminosidade: 1185,
      bmp280Altitude: 653.58,
      bmp280Pressao: 94739,
      csmsv12Solo: 40.76,
      dht22Temperatura: 27.9,
      dht22Umidade: 31.7,
      mhrdMolhamento: -0.04,
      pluviometro: 0,
      timestamp: 1598554509834,
      uvm30aIndiceUv: 1
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to know why the return inside the function is not the same as outside the function.
I would like the end result to be the same from within the function.
Can anyone give me a light?

**Edit** - Sorry again now my fuction is this way

```
public async findLatestWeatherStationRecord(): Promise<WeatherStation> {
  const Ref = database.ref('Prototipo0/Leitura/');
  const snapshot = await Ref.limitToLast(1).once('value');

  let latestWeatherStationRecord;

  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    database
      .ref(`Prototipo0/Leitura/${child.key}`)
      .limitToLast(1)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          latestWeatherStationRecord = childSnapshot.val();
          // console.log(latestWeatherStationRecord);
          return latestWeatherStationRecord;
        });
      });
  });
  console.log(latestWeatherStationRecord);
// I need to return the snapshot function, but I can't
  return latestWeatherStationRecord;
}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: sorry, i think it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the promise that is returned by `once()`, but are using the callback to do your processing. This means your `return` still runs before your processing.

The solution is to separate the `await` from the rest of your processing:

```
const snapshot = await RefR.limitToLast(1).once("value");
let latestWeatherStationRecord;
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
  child.forEach(childSnapshot => {
    latestWeatherStationRecord = childSnapshot.val();
  });
});
return latestWeatherStationRecord;
```

Comment: this way the cosole.log outside the function returns undefined.

Comment: "the cosole.log outside the function" Which `console.log` is that?

Comment: if I make a console.log from "latestWeatherStationRecord" it returns me undefined.

Comment: That means you're doing something else wrong after the `await`. If you update your question to show what you've done, I can have a look.

Comment: I updated my question, I'm sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: You're loading the data again, which is again an asynchronous operation. It's also not needed, so I updated my answer to contain the entire code that I think you need. If this doesn't work, step through this code in a debugger, and check what each line does, and where it goes wrong.